# Is there a way to shorten this if statement?

Tags: python, python-3.x, boolean

I am trying to make it so that if two or more variables are False, then the statement ends; but the way I'm doing it, the code is taking up way too much space.

```
if g == False and h == False:
  print("Use a different formula.")
  return
elif g == False and i == False:
  print("Use a different formula.")
  return
elif g == False and c == False:
  print("Use a different formula.")
  return
elif h == False and i == False:
  print("Use a different formula.")
  return
elif h == False and c == False:
  print("Use a different formula.")
  return
elif i == False and c == False:
  print("Use a different formula.")
  return
elif g == False and h == False and i == False:
  print("Use a different formula.")
  return
elif g == False and h == False and c == False:
  print("Use a different formula.")
  return
elif h == False and i == False and c == False:
  print("Use a different formula.")
  return
elif c == False and i == False and g == False:
  print("Use a different formula.")
  return
elif g == False and h == False and i == False and c == False:
  print("Use a different formula.")
  return
```

This is what I have and it technically should work, but there has to be a way to shorten this. Please help.

Comment: Not really an answer, but you shouldn't use `x == False`. Either `x is False`, or just `not x` is preferable.

Comment: Also, if multiple conditions lead to the same result, you can always combine them into a single condition with `or`, which will short-circuit nicely.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Python's Boolean values `True` and `False` can be treated arithmetically as the integers `1` and `0` respectively. So if you add them together and the result is less than or equal to 2, then at least two must be false.

```py
if g + h + c + i <= 2:
    ...
```

As @MadPhysicist notes in the comments, this works because `bool` is a subclass of `int`.

Comment: The idea is good, but that doesn't actually help change the statement into something more useable.

Comment: @MadPhysicist What do you mean by "usable" in this context? Are you really of the opinion that a single condition is not better than 11 separate conditions with the rest of the code repeated 11 times?

Comment: I see now. You are interpreting each occurrence of `print("Use a different formula.")` as being a standin for the *same* code. I was assuming it to be different code in each case. You are absolutely right.

Comment: It's simply a way to shorten the condition which the OP wrote in English as *"two or more variables are False"*.

Comment: Of course. I completely misread the question. I was expecting it to be a bit more complicated than it really is. Vote definitely flipped. This is the right way to do it.

Comment: You may want to explicitly add that `bool` is actually a subclass of `int` in Python.